# Showing images on Scattering Graph as plot symbols in Core plot iOS

Tags: iphone, xcode, graph, core-plot

I have a requirement of showing images at the plot symbols in my scattering Graph. Right now I am using CPTPlotSymbol to plot symbols on the graph. But all I can get with it are the predefined objects. Eg. ellipsePlotSymbol, dashPlotSymbol, trianglePlotSymbol.

But I need to plot an image instead.

Could you help me in acheiving this. Thanks a lot.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got the answer after trying a bit.

First of all, I built a Custom CPTLayer and inside it used the image to be filled.

**CustomImageForScatterPlot.h file**

```
 #import "CPTLayer.h"


 @interface CustomImageForScatterPlot : CPTLayer
 {    
     UIImage *_image;

 }
 -(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image;

 @end
```

**CustomImageForScatterPlot.m file**

```
#import "CustomImageForScatterPlot.h"
#import "CPTLayer.h"

@implementation CustomImageForScatterPlot

-(void)dealloc{

    [_image release];
    [super dealloc];
}
-(id)initWithImage:(UIImage *)image{

    CGRect f = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:f]) {

        _image = [image retain];
    }

    return self;

}

-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, self.bounds, _image.CGImage);

}
@end
```

NOW, in the Scatter plot graph file, I used the following delegate method to return the images

```
- (CPTLayer *)dataLabelForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{       
     CustomImageForScatterPlot* layer = [[CustomImageForScatterPlot alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"dots.png"]];
     layer.frame = CGRectMake(2, 0, 34, 6);

     return layer;        
}
```

ENJOY CODING.... :)

Comment: it's not working for me..
dataLabelForPlot is called, but image doesn't appear..
any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-symbolForScatterPlot:recordIndex:` datasource method and return a different symbol for the highlighted point. A standard rectangular symbol with an image `fill` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I see two different ways of accomplishing this, the first would be to use one of the default symbols, then iterate through your data and add a CPTPlotSpaceAnnotation with a CPTLayer containing an image at each point.  The other way would to create a subclass of CPTPlotSymbol and override renderAsVectorInContext to draw an image.

There may be a direct way to do this that i don't know of.

Comment: i have this method... - (CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
could i provide an image inside CPTPlotSymbol itself?

Comment: The only method CPTPlotSymbol provides for creating a custom symbol is  +(CPTPlotSymbol *)customPlotSymbolWithPath:(CGPathRef)aPath;  So if you can make your custom symbol with a CGPathRef that will work, but otherwise i think you will need to create a subclass of CPTPlotSymbol