# Core-Plot: How to center custom image plot symbol

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, plot, core-plot

I'm using a custom image symbol, as described in [Showing images on Scattering Graph as plot symbols in Core plot iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362277/showing-images-on-scattering-graph-as-plot-symbols-in-core-plot-ios). Also refer to [Positioning label on CPTBarPlot (Core-Plot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475573/positioning-label-on-cbtbarplot-core-plot/14675747) regarding positioning of the data label in a `CPTPlot`.

However, I'm not seeing the behavior from `CPTScatterPlot.labelOffset` that I need. Positive values increase the distance between the image bottom and the point, while negative values increase the distance between the image top and the point. I need to center the image on the point. See screenshots:

- positive labelOffset values: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1uSe.png]
- negative labelOffset values: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9fkL.png]

My solution is hacky and requires me to modify the image frame in my `CustomImageForScatterPlot`'s `drawInContext` method. Any ideas on how to make `labelOffset` work how I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That behavior is correct for data labels. You want to use a plot symbol.

```
-(CPTPlotSymbol *)symbolForScatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot
                           recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CPTPlotSymbol *symbol = nil;

    if ( /* use symbol for this index? */ ) {
        symbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
        symbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithImage:/* symbol image */];
        symbol.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    }

    return symbol;
}
```

If you want every point to have a symbol, set the `plotSymbol` property instead of implementing this datasource method.

Comment: Thanks, you're right I was previously using `dataLabelForPlot`. FYI for others, the symbol image in the code sample above can reference a PNG resource using: `[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon_volume" ofType:@"png"]]`.

Comment: Except when you use the asset catalog :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485453/creating-cptimages-from-images-in-xcassets-file