# Creating CPTImages from images in xcassets file

Tags: core-plot, asset-catalog, cptimage

So according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18968352/access-asset-catalog-pathforresource), you have to use `imageNamed` for loading images now in iOS.

Unfortunately, CPTImage's constructors requires paths for loading images

So something like this:
`[CPTImage imageForPNGFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"plotsymbol" ofType:@"png"]]`

These `-pathForResource` calls now fail because of asset catalogs.

So.. has anyone been able to do this? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CPTImage` class will include an `imageNamed` method in a future release. It is available now on the release 2.0 branch. People are using the 2.0 code now but it is unfinished and subject to change in many areas before the final release.

Comment: Good answer. I just added the image the old way and used pathForResource. 

Any release date on 2.0?

Comment: No release date for 2.0 yet. There is still quite a bit of work left.